# Boost 1.81.0 (chrono and thread) library compilation is failing with Sun Studio 12.5

Tags: boost, boost-thread, sunstudio, boost-system, boost-chrono

Facing below error when i am compiling chrono or thread alone in sun studio 12.5
Error I am getting while build boost thread/ chrono is below

```
"CC" -std=c++11 -m64 -xarch=sparc -mt  -lCstd -xO4 -mt -erroff=%none -xldscope=hidden -m64 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_BUILD_LIB=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_DONT_USE_CHRONO -DBOOST_THREAD_POSIX -DNDEBUG -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/thread/build/sun/release/address-model-64/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/future.o" "libs/thread/src/future.cpp"
...failed sun.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/thread/build/sun/release/address-model-64/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/future.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/thread/build/sun/release/address-model-64/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden>libboost_thread.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/thread/build/sun/release/address-model-64/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden>pthread/thread.o...
...skipped <p/export/home/ramesh/compiled_library/boost_1_81_0/lib>libboost_thread.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/thread/build/sun/release/address-model-64/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden>libboost_thread.a...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/thread/build/sun/release/address-model-64/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden>libboost_thread-variant-static.cmake for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/thread/build/sun/release/address-model-64/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden>libboost_thread.a...
...skipped <p/export/home/ramesh/compiled_library/boost_1_81_0/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.81.0>libboost_thread-variant-static.cmake for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/thread/build/sun/release/address-model-64/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden>libboost_thread-variant-static.cmake...
sun.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/thread/build/sun/release/address-model-64/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/pthread/thread.o
"./boost/system/detail/error_condition.hpp", line 298: Error: type is not a member of boost::system::detail::enable_if<0, void>.
"./boost/system/detail/error_condition.hpp", line 272: Error: type is not a member of boost::system::detail::enable_if<0, void>.
"./boost/system/detail/error_condition.hpp", line 310: Error: type is not a member of boost::system::detail::enable_if<0, void>.
"./boost/system/detail/error_condition.hpp", line 284: Error: type is not a member of boost::system::detail::enable_if<0, void>.
"./boost/system/detail/error_condition.hpp", line 298: Error: type is not a member of boost::system::detail::enable_if<0, void>.
"./boost/system/detail/error_condition.hpp", line 272: Error: type is not a member of boost::system::detail::enable_if<0, void>.
"./boost/system/detail/error_condition.hpp", line 298: Error: type is not a member of boost::system::detail::enable_if<0, void>.
"./boost/system/detail/error_condition.hpp", line 272: Error: type is not a member of boost::system::detail::enable_if<0, void>.
"./boost/system/detail/error_condition.hpp", line 310: Error: type is not a member of boost::system::detail::enable_if<0, void>.
"./boost/system/detail/error_condition.hpp", line 284: Error: type is not a member of boost::system::detail::enable_if<0, void>.
"./boost/system/detail/error_condition.hpp", line 310: Error: type is not a member of boost::system::detail::enable_if<0, void>.
"./boost/system/detail/error_condition.hpp", line 284: Error: type is not a member of boost::system::detail::enable_if<0, void>.
"./boost/system/detail/error_code.hpp", line 173: Error: Too many arguments in cast to boost::system::error_code.
"./boost/system/detail/error_code.hpp", line 190: Error: Too many arguments in cast to boost::system::error_code.
"./boost/system/detail/error_code.hpp", line 195: Error: Too many arguments in cast to boost::system::error_code.
"./boost/system/detail/error_code.hpp", line 200: Error: Too many arguments in cast to boost::system::error_code.
"./boost/system/detail/std_category_impl.hpp", line 62: Error: Too many initializers for bc.
"./boost/system/detail/std_category_impl.hpp", line 67: Error: Too many initializers for bc.
"./boost/system/detail/std_category_impl.hpp", line 75: Error: Too many initializers for bc.
"./boost/system/errc.hpp", line 36: Error: Too many arguments in cast to boost::system::error_code.
"./boost/system/errc.hpp", line 42: Error: Too many arguments in cast to boost::system::error_code.
"./boost/system/system_error.hpp", line 38: Error: Too many arguments in cast to boost::system::error_code.
"./boost/system/system_error.hpp", line 38: Error: Too many initializers for code_.
"./boost/system/system_error.hpp", line 41: Error: Too many arguments in cast to boost::system::error_code.
"./boost/system/system_error.hpp", line 41: Error: Too many initializers for code_.
Compilation aborted, too many Error messages.
[1:40 PM]
```

Using Same compiler option (C++11) all other libraries in boost able to build. These two Chrono and thread is giving similar to above error. Above error pasted is from boost thread compilation.

**Command which have used to build:**

```
./b2 install address-model=64 runtime-link=shared "cflags=-std=c++11 linkflags=-std=c++11" threading=multi toolset=sun --prefix=/export/home/ramesh/compiled_library/boost_1_81_0/ --with-chrono
```

Environment

```
Sun OS:5.10 Sparc
Compiler: Sun studio 12.5
```

**Command which have used to build:**
./b2 install address-model=64 runtime-link=shared "cflags=-std=c++11 linkflags=-std=c++11" threading=multi toolset=sun --prefix=/export/home/ramesh/compiled_library/boost_1_81_0/ --with-chrono

Comment: I don't see Sun/Sparc in the test matrix https://www.boost.org/development/tests/master/developer/summary.html have you checked the official support status?

Comment: It does look like a compiler issue, where the compiler doesn't correctly SFINAE the operators that have been touched in relation to [issue #93](https://github.com/boostorg/system/issues/91). You might want to take it up there, or open a new issue against the Boost System repository

Comment: Thanks for the info, have raised issue in boost-system git https://github.com/boostorg/system/issues/107